# When to use Twitter Bootstrap and when to HTML5 Boilerplate?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

I am pretty bad with CSS and HTML5 designing/templates. So, I google around and found two frameworks to start with nice looking layouts, necessary js and html5 support. But I don't know which on to use.

I would appreciate your answers on

1. What is the main different between two except google analytics  ?
2. Which one is more rails friendly ?
3. Which one fits best to e-commerce sites, i.e. create rich content, integrate with user management frameworks  etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine them and use them both - http://www.initializr.com/

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 Boilerplate (H5BP) is a starting project template that is designed to be adapted to your needs. Bootstrap is a specialized, modular, HTML/CSS/JS toolkit.

boilerplate provides you with a best practice HTML5 document, some reset CSS and a lot of javascript goodness like modernizer.js; this Twitter toolkit provides you with stylesheets that define a lot more than just a reset.

The Twitter toolkit is better compared to CSS frameworks like blueprintcss and 960 grid system and positions itself somewhere in between those two. Twitter bootstrap comes with its own fixed look and feel so you can concentrate on your content and logic.

checkout this [Quora Thread](http://www.quora.com/Is-Bootstrap-a-complement-OR-an-alternative-to-HTML5-Boilerplate-or-viceversa)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I gather you misunderstand what these two projects are. "Google analytics" is not the difference.

Expanding on what @thomas has already stated, Boilerplate contains starter HTML templates with best practices built-in and Bootstrap is a library of CSS and JS UI elements. They are not mutually exclusive.

You may want to look at initializer as @Zlatan has already recommended, or [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com), which is an extension framework for Twitter Bootstrap.